# Для чего нужны @types/library-name в TypeScipt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Всем привет!

Впервые столкнулся с TypeScript в React приложении. Подскажите, для чего нужно ставить библиотеки с префиксом @types/ и для чего это нужно?

Например, я поставил redux-logger, но VS Code ругается и требует поставить еще @types/redux-logger.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию typescript использует путь `node_modules/@types/<package_name>` для разрешения типизации установленного вами пакета. Говоря простым языком, тайпскрипту необходимо брать информацию об интерфейсах и т.п., для этого и ставятся данные пакеты. Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types).